# LPC11C24 MCU to control DAC8718

Tags: microcontroller, dac

I am trying to use an LPC11C24 microcontroller to send digital values to a [DAC8718](http://www.ti.com.cn/cn/lit/ds/symlink/dac8718.pdf) to convert to an analog voltage value. I am attempting to communicate via SPI and I am using `mbed.h` with the `SPI.h` capability to send an arbitrary stream of bits to the DAC. However I am not seeing any output on the DAC output. I am communicating via a PCAN-USB dongle. Here is my code:

```
#include "mbed.h"

CAN can(NC, NC);
DigitalOut chipsel(P2_0);


int main() {
  // Init CAN
  can.frequency(125000);
  // Main loop
  SPI device(P2_3, P2_2, P2_1);
  device.frequency(1000000);
  device.format(16,2); // 16 bits
  chipsel = 0;
  chipsel = 1;
  float response;

  while(1) {
    response = device.write(0xFFFF);
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and what should I do to record output on the DAC?

Comment: I'm assuming the SPI.h is included in the mbed.h header?

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you want to do a Read back write operation, try this:

```
#include "mbed.h"

CAN can(NC, NC);
DigitalOut chipsel(P2_0);


int main() {
// Init CAN
can.frequency(125000);
// Main loop
SPI device(P2_3, P2_2, P2_1);
device.frequency(1000000);
device.format(8,3); // 16 bits
chipsel = 0;
chipsel = 1; - remove this
float response;

while(1) {
    chipsel = 0;
    device.write(0x88FFFF); // dont need to care about response, writes max voltage to DAC0, look on page 47 and 48 of TI docs
    chipsel = 1;
    // wait some time here, not sure about wait timing here
    chipsel = 0;
    response = device.write (0xFFFFFF); // write NOP command and read data returned
    chipsel = 1;
    // do whatever with response
}

}
```